# htaccess redirect to subdomain and keep string

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Found a few similar questions but either I cant figure it out from the answers or they dont directly match my needs.

What I am trying to achieve is this:

I recently moved part of my site to a sub domain on a different server so what used to be in: `http://mysite.com/clients` is now on `http://clients.mysite.com`

using: `RedirectMatch 301 https?://mysite.com/clients/^(.*)$ https://clients.mysite.com/$1` works fine for simply redirecting people hitting `http://mysite.com/clients` to the new sub domain however I would like to be able to preserve the string after /clients/

so if someone hits e.g. `http://mysite.com/clients/could_be_a_number_of_things.php` it redirects to `http://clients.mysite.com/could_be_a_number_of_things.php`

Can anyone advise?

full .htaccess as requested:

```
    # -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
#AuthName mysite.com
#AuthUserFile /home/inhost/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
#AuthGroupFile /home/inhost/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp

# BEGIN WordPress
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^clients/(.*)$ http%1://clients.mysite.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: It looks like the redirect is pretty fine but I am no Apache config expert. I just saw that `^(.*)$` won't match anything with the hostname before. Try to remove the carot `^` which means *start of string*. Maybe it will then match the trailing URL path correctly.

Comment: Tried that, same results :( I am now using RedirectMatch 301 ^https?://inceptionhosting.com/clients/(.*)$ https://clients.inceptionhosting.com/$1
based on a suggestion but that has not helped either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory on `mysite.com` server:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^clients/(.*)$ http%1://clients.mysite.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: That pastebin URL is not accessible for me, please post your full .htaccess in your question. Also tell me what URI did you try and where (server, directory path) do you have your .htaccess file?

Comment: Odd it loads fine here, in the question as requested. 

Appreciate the help btw!

Comment: Thanks for putting .htaccess, didn't know that WP is also in the picture. Can you move my suggested rules to the top of this .htaccess? Also I believe this .htaccess is on `mysite.com` server, right?