# <http:// to http://www.> and <https:// to https://www.>

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There is not much to say, because I wanna try to explain it easy.

Is there any way to create a .htaccess that does these things:

> example.com > **http://www.** example.com
>
> *http://* example.com > http:// **www.** example.com
>
> *https://* example.com > https:// **www.** example.com

What I mean is like:

1. if its http, it goes to the `http + www`
2. if its https it goes to the `https + www`
3. if **nothing** is in the front of the domain, it goes to the `http + www`

I've tried to make it work with another code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

That code ALMOST works, the only thing that is **wrong** about it, is that when its **https://** example.com it redirects to **http://** *www.* example.com

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that doesn't work, you can write a separate rule for https and http:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xplayrs.com/$1  [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xplayrs.com/$1  [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Well, it seems to this code does the same problem as mine does :v

Comment: This is pretty well tested code (you can search few of my accepted answers with above code). Is there any chance somewhere in your code it is not jumping from https to http?

Comment: hm, well you can see it for yourself on my page, here: https://xplayrs.com/ (Notice that the link is with https:// and 
**not** added www.)

Comment: Ah crap, I had a typo there. Instead of `%{HTTPS}` I typed `{HTTPS}` :( Really sorry about that, please check the edited answer now.

Comment: >:/ It does still not work. D: Check the comment with the link, it seems to it still redirects to the http://

Comment: Sorry that forgot to respond later, i tried Jon Lin's and that worked, so if you clicked on the link, it will redirect you to the correct one, sorry I forgot to tell that. (If you dint check while your code where active)

Comment: Sure np, whatever works for you :) btw here is another recent question (and very similar one to you) that I answered and worked for the OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883671/htaccess-redirect-to-subdomain-and-keep-string/10886690#10886690